# vine identification?

Tags: identification, vines

I'm trying to figure out what this vine is. Haven't been around for spring and summer so I'm unsure of the flower type. Any ideas? From googling, maybe it's a morning glory? This is in Rochester NY, zone 6 I think. [image]

Comment: Handsome leaves. Most Morning Glory look like hearts or arrows.

Comment: Eyeballs as very similar: https://permies.com/t/38393/Plant-ID-Pretty-type-bindweed and perhaps it's a bit hairy if I zoom in the photo? Perhaps not. Looks too much like a bindweed for me to be happy having around, anyway.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It's definitely not that particular bindweed, the leaves and vines are smooth, not hairy in person. Also, it's not too aggressively rooting as far as I can tell...

Comment: Possibly Fallopia baldschuanica (Russian vine). The flowers should tell you definitively.